# Ajax function not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a button in my page, when I click on this button it redirect me to this link `readMessage/id`.

I want when I click on it to stay in the same page, I don't want my page to be reloaded or something else.

The link `readMessage/id` will update the database, which is a function in a controller :

```
function readMessage($id) {
            $this->message_module->readMessage($id);
            $this->index();
      }
```

This function will call the `readMessage` function in the `message` module :

```
function readMessage($id) {

        $data = array('is_read' => 1);

        $this->db->where('id',(int)$id)
                ->update($_tbl_msg, $data);
  }
```

This is my button :

```
<button class="testButton" data-id="<?php echo $message->id; ?>">Test</button>
```

And this is the code I tried :

```
$('.testButton').click(function(){

                // get jquery object access to the button
                var $thisButton = $(this);

                var form_data = {
                    id : $thisButton.data('id')
                }

                $.ajax({
                   url:'<?php echo base_url;?>messages/readMessage',
                   type:'GET',
                   data: form_data,
                   success:function(d){
                       alert(d);
                   }
                });
                
            });
```

But it's not working.

If someone could show me how to do that I'll be thankful.

## Edit 1:

I changed the ajax code, and it worked I can see now the alert box which is in the `success` attribut :

```
$('.testButton').click(function(){

                $.ajax({
                   url:"<?php echo site_url('messages/readMessage'); ?>",
                   type:'GET',
                   data: {id : $(this).data('id')},
                   success:function(d){
                       alert(d);
                   }
                });
                
            });
```

I think the URL after that will be : `messages/readMessage?id=myId` , but in CodeIgniter it should be : `messages/readMessage/myId`, that's why it doesn't work.

I did a test by giving the `id` manually  :

```
url:"<?php echo site_url('messages/readMessage/5'); ?>"
```

And it worked.

Now I need to know how to concat that value `$(this).data('id')` with the `url`, because when I tried this : `url:"<?php echo site_url('messages/readMessage/" + $(this).data('id') + "'); ?>"`, it didn't worked.

Comment: check chrome console's network tab.any errors?

Comment: Nope, there is no error at all.

Comment: @Arunu please check the modification I made.

Comment: use post instead of get

Comment: Do you catch up the $_GET variable in your PHP function? I can only see that you send through ajax.

Comment: You seem to be using the variable id when in your button, it is actually data-id. Can you please clarify that?

Comment: @VincentEdwardGedariaBinua : When I declare an attributs as `data-name` I can retrieve it's value using that name.

Comment: $(this).data('id') should return the ID attribute of the button with class testButton, right? however that ID isn't actually set. you have set it to data-id, which should probably return a value. Can you check on that first please? Maybe you may want to use $(this).data('data-id') instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your recent edit, try below code in url section

```
url:"<?php echo site_url('messages/readMessage'); ?>/"+$(this).data('id'),
```

Then your `readMessage` should accept a parameter as below

```
function readMessage($data ="") {
```

Answer (score 1):

In you controller 
try by echoing

```
function readMessage() {
  $id=$this->input->get('id');
        $this->message_module->readMessage($id);
        $this->index();
    echo "something";
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't echo anything.